# Getting null pointer while writing log in cucumber report

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

To Write log in the report, I added @Before hook in definition file

```
private Scenario scenario;

@Before()
public void before(Scenario scenario) {
    this.scenario = scenario;
}

@Given("Attach sample log in report")
public void attachSampleLogInReport() {
    scenario.log("Log Attached");
}
```

Here the concerns is I need to add @Before hook in each definitation, to overcome this
In TestContext File Scenario is added
**TextContext.java**

```
public class TestContext {

    @Getter @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    AppiumDriver appiumDriver;

    @Getter
    @Accessors(fluent = true)
    ScenarioContext scenarioContext;

    @Getter
    @Accessors(fluent = true)
    PageObjectManager pageObjectManager;

    @Getter @Setter
    private Scenario scenario;

    public TestContext() {
        if (GenericDriverFactory.getMobileDriverManager().getDriver() == null){
            new AppiumServerManager().startServer();
            GenericDriverManager genericDriverManager = GenericDriverFactory.getMobileDriverManager();
            genericDriverManager.initializeDriver();
        }
        setAppiumDriver(GenericDriverFactory.getMobileDriverManager().getDriver());

        scenarioContext = new ScenarioContext();
        pageObjectManager = new PageObjectManager();
    }
}
```

**AssertHook.java**

```
public class AssertHook {

    TestContext testContext;
    
    public AssertHook(TestContext context) {
        testContext = context;
    }
    
    @Before
    public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) {
        testContext.setScenario(scenario); // here I am setting the value
        System.out.println("GET Scenario " + testContext.getScenario().getId()); // Value printed  GET Scenario 1b6ee801-f753-465b-93df-38c1036428fa
    }
}
```

**DefinationFile**

```
@Given("Attach sample log in report")
public void attachSampleLogInReport() {
      testContext.getScenario().log("Demo: Attach log in report");
}
```

but here in step definition file Getting

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "io.cucumber.java.Scenario.log(String)" because the return value of
> "utilities.cucumber.context.TestContext.getScenario()" is null

Comment: Cucumber does not support field injection without some extra DI libraries.

Comment: I have already  pico-container dependency

Comment: Then you should inject that field when you construct your object. Define the constructor for your class that would take `Scenario` and assign that field from a constructor.